# how to revealed Views in my page by Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I tried to be revealed Views in my web page by Django.
but I couldn't. even I tried several solutions that suggested by ChatGPT.

theses are my codes

1. models.py

```
class PostView(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Views for Post: {self.question}'

it's my code for create views for each question
```

1-1. models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author_question')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    voter = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='voter_question')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_question')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

and it's Question model that is established the connection with PostView model.

and after I wrote this code. I ran 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'

2. base_views.py

```
def view_question(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    
    post_views, created = PostView.objects.get_or_create(question=question)
    
    post_views.views += 1
    post_views.save()
    
    context = {'question': question, 'post_views': post_views}
    return render(request, 'pybo/question_detail.html', context)
```

3. url.py

```
   path('question/list/',base_views.index, name='index'),
   path('quesiton/list/<str:category_name>/', base_views.index, name='index'),
   path('question/detail/<int:question_id>/', base_views.detail, name='detail'),
   path('question/detail/<int:question_id>/',
     base_views.view_question, name='views_question'),
```

4. template

```
                        {% if question_list %}
                        {% for question in question_list %}
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td>{{question_list.paginator.count|sub:question_list.start_index|sub:forloop.counter0|add:1 }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% if question.voter.all.count > 0 %}
                                <span class="badge badge-warning px-2 py-1">
                                    {{ question.voter.all.count}}
                                </span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <a href="{% url 'pybo:detail' question.id %}">
                                    {{ question.subject }}
                                </a>
                                {% if question.answer_set.count > 0 %}
                                <span class="text-danger small ml-2">
                                    {{ question.answer_set.count }}
                                </span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ question.author.username }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% with question.postviews_set.first as post_views %}
                                {{ post_views.views }}
                                {% endwith %}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ question.create_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

it's only revealed spaces for views but it didn't revealed any number even I set a default value as 0 in my model.
I tried to get solutions to ChatGPT and Did what they suggested but I can't solve this problem.
and also tried to find my faults about spelling by ChatGPT and it didn't occur any missed spelling.

I would be really happy if you give any advice about this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No where in your `view_question()` function are you returning `question_list` in your context, so there's nothing to iterate over in your template. Also once you fix that you're going to have issues setting the iterator to the same name as a template object you're passing in already.

Also I'm sure it's just because it wasn't copy and pasted but make sure all statements in your template have their closing statement as well. `{% endif %}`